# How to fix error 'Connection Refused' when communicating with TCP between two devices

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, pthreads, beagleboneblack

So I'm currently attempting to communicate over TCP from a beaglebone black running debian to a mac. I want to communicate from the beaglebone to the mac and send text messages between the two. The way my code is set up is I have a main connection where I'm streaming a video over port 1000 using a UDP connection, and this works fine by itself, but I've set up a basic TCP connection to send text over port 10001 in a separate pthread, and when connecting between the two devices it gives me the output

```
ERROR connecting -1 Connection refused 111
```

Where if I print out the values it says

```
Port: 10001, name: 192.168.1.37
```

What's particularly interesting to me is that I know the IP address is right because I can stream video using the IP address and port 10000.

The overall setup is I have a beaglebone microcontroller (basically a raspberry pi) wired up to a router, and my mac connected by ethernet to the same router. I'm using the library "sys/socket.h"

TCPClient code (macbook side)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

class TCPClient {

private:
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[512];

    void createSocket() {

        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if (sockfd < 0) {
            printf("ERROR opening socket\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    void createConnection() {

        memcpy((char *)server->h_addr_list[0],
               (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
               server->h_length);

        int er = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        if (er < 0) {
            printf("ERROR connecting %i %s\n", er, strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }
    }

public:
    TCPClient(int port, char* name) {

        memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

        printf("Port: %i, name: %s\n", port, name);

        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

        server = gethostbyname(name);
        if (server == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        createSocket();

        createConnection();

    }

    ~TCPClient() {
        close(sockfd);
    }

    void transmitData(char data[]) {

        int n = write(sockfd, data, strlen(data));
        if (n < 0) {
            printf("ERROR writing to socket\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    char* receiveData() {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        int n = read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (n < 0) {
            printf("ERROR reading from socket\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        return buffer;
    }

};
```

TCPServer code (microcontroller)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

class TCPServer {

private:
    // struct for data
    int sockfd, newsockfd;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[512];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

public:
    TCPServer(int port) {

        // clear address structure
        memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

        // setup the host_addr structure for use in bind call
        // server byte order
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        // automatically be filled with current host's IP address
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        // Create socket
        // socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
        // i.e. IPV_4, TCP, default
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if (sockfd < 0) {
            printf("ERROR opening socket\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        // Create bind
        if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
            printf("ERROR on binding\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        // start listening
        // This listen() call tells the socket to listen to the incoming connections.
        // The listen() function places all incoming connection into a backlog queue
        // until `() call accepts the connection.
        // Here, we set the maximum size for the backlog queue to 5.
        listen(sockfd, 5);

        // The accept() call actually accepts an incoming connection
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

        // This accept() function will write the connecting client's address info
        // into the the address structure and the size of that structure is clilen.
        // The accept() returns a new socket file descriptor for the accepted connection.
        // So, the original socket file descriptor can continue to be used
        // for accepting new connections while the new socker file descriptor is used for
        // communicating with the connected client.
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        printf("Ending accept function\n");

        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            printf("ERROR on accept");
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n",
               inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));

    }

    ~TCPServer() {
        close(newsockfd);
        close(sockfd);
    }

    void createSocket() {
        // create a socket
        // socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
        // i.e. IPV_4, TCP, default
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if (sockfd < 0) {
            printf("ERROR opening socket\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    void transmitData(char data[]) {
        // This send() function sends the 13 bytes of the string to the new socket
        send(newsockfd, data, strlen(data), 0);

    }

    char* receiveData() {

        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        int n = read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (n < 0) {
            printf("ERROR reading from socket\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        return buffer;

    }

};
```

And here is the code I used to create the connection; this is the portion that runs on my desktop computer (receives connection and displays output code)

```
void* sensor_com(void* conn_data_void) {
    struct conn *conn_data = (struct conn*)conn_data_void;

    printf("printing from pthread\n");
    printf("port: %d \n", (*conn_data).port);

    TCPServer *sensor_com = new TCPServer(conn_data->port);

    char *buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*256);

    while(1) {

        // receive data from ROV and translate json
        char *buffer = (*sensor_com).receiveData();
        std::string json(buffer);

        picojson::value v;

        std::string err = picojson::parse(v, json);
        if (! err.empty()) {
        std:cerr << err << std::endl;
        }

        // check if the type of the value is "object"
        if (! v.is<picojson::object>()) {
            std::cerr << "JSON is not an object" << std::endl;
            exit(2);
        }

        std::map<std::string, string> data;

        // obtain a const reference to the map, and print the contents
        const picojson::value::object& obj = v.get<picojson::object>();
        for (picojson::value::object::const_iterator i = obj.begin();
             i != obj.end();
             ++i) {
            data[i->first] = i->second.to_str();
        }

        cout << "accel_x of rov: " << data["accel_x"] << endl;
        cout << "accel_y of rov: " << data["accel_y"] << endl;
        cout << "accel_z of rov: " << data["accel_z"] << endl;
        cout << "gyro_x of rov: " << data["gyro_x"] << endl;
        cout << "gyro_y of rov: " << data["gyro_y"] << endl;
        cout << "gyro_z of rov: " << data["gyro_z"] << endl;

    }

    free(buf);

    return NULL;

}
```

And this is the portion on the microcontroller/beaglebone

void* sensor_com(void* conn_data_void) {

```
struct conn *conn_data = (struct conn*)conn_data_void;
unsigned int port = (*conn_data).port;

printf("printing from pthread\n");
printf("port: %d \n", port);

// create TCP connection includeing socket and connection call
TCPClient *sensor_com = new TCPClient(conn_data->port, conn_data->host);

char* val;

// Data from MPU6050
struct sensor_data movement;

if (RUNNING_ON_BEAGLEBONE) {
    initialize_i2c();
}

// send data to master forever
while (1) {

    if (RUNNING_ON_BEAGLEBONE) {
        // collect data from I2C_interface
        get_data(&movement);
    } else {
        // get data here
        movement.accel_x = 10;
        movement.accel_y = 10;
        movement.accel_z = 10;
        movement.gyro_x = 10;
        movement.gyro_y = 10;
        movement.gyro_z = 10;
    }
    // Create json for data to be stored
    string data = "{";

    // Add accelleration data
    data += "\"accel_x\": \"" + std::to_string(movement.accel_x) + "\",";
    data += "\"accel_y\": \"" + std::to_string(movement.accel_y) + "\",";
    data += "\"accel_z\": \"" + std::to_string(movement.accel_z) + "\",";

    // Add gyroscopic dataa
    data += "\"gyro_x\": \"" + std::to_string(movement.gyro_x) + "\",";
    data += "\"gyro_y\": \"" + std::to_string(movement.gyro_y) + "\",";
    data += "\"gyro_z\": \"" + std::to_string(movement.gyro_z) + "\"}";

    // convert to char array
    char *charData = new char [data.length()+1];
    strcpy(charData, data.c_str());

    (*sensor_com).transmitData(charData);

    // delay for readability
    sleep(2);

}

free(val);

return NULL;
```

}

I apologize for the wall of code, though frankly I think the issue has to do with the connection in between so I don't know if it'll be useful. The code works fine when it's on the same machine (it's only communicating between machines that there's an issue). I've also tried using tcpdump but I can't figure out how to use it to send packets to another server, I'm starting to think it's just for listening to packets in which case it isn't very helpful.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Connection refused is the result of the server (or something betwween the server and the client) responding to a connection attempt, SYN packet, with a RST packet. Make sure both sides agree on the port to use and that there are no firewalls in the way (though usually a firewall ignores the connection request and doesn't respond).

Comment: I'm not reading all that, but how to fix 'connection refused' is simply to make sure the server's socket is listening before you try to connect.

Comment: Use `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :10001` on the server to make sure the port is open. Another handy tool to have on hand at the client side is Wireshark. It's fairly easy to use.

Comment: @user4581301 I couldn't get your netstat command to work as written but I was able to run 'lsof -nP -i4TCP:10001 | grep LISTEN' which I think does a similar thing, and it gave me 'master  69540 Thomas    3u  IPv4 0xce53c41035f69957      0t0  TCP *:10001 (LISTEN)', so I think this means the server port is listening. I've also disabled my firewall on my mac and there isn't a firewall on the microcontroller

Comment: Looks good assuming "master" is the name of your server program and not a Doctor Who villain hacking your computer. Either way it sure looks like the port is open and being attended to. Recommendation: make a new program that does nothing but open and listen on this one port. This gives you a smaller, easier-to-manage test case you can use and abuse until you crack the case. Also gives you something closer to a [mcve]. If the little program doesn't reproduce the problem, the bug is somewhere else.

Comment: @user4581301 So I did set up a simpler version of the code, which just establishes the connection and sends one char array. This works fine when it's on just my computer but it fails when it's going between the two hosts (my mac and the beaglebone). I've been reconfiguring the network over and over but it always fails, do you have any recommendations for setting up the network so it can communicate over TCP? I'm at a loss (I've already disabled my firewall and I've been trying connections where I plug it directly into my laptop and going through the router)

Comment: Quick tests: Can the beaglebone send to itself? Are you absolutely certain you're getting the correct address out of `gethostbyname`?

Answer (score 0):

So I sort of figured out the problem, thanks in large part to @user4581301

I ended up trying to rebuild the simplest version I could, and what I found was that the original source I based a lot of my code off of was the issue(I can't find the link but it was just a tutorial). It worked on either machine independently but if you tried to send data between two machines it wouldn't work (possibly something to do with different libraries between the debian os on the beaglebone and mac os on my laptop, or just some of the functions were depreciated).

I ended up rebuilding the TCP connection from this site (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) which used newer techniques and was able to work across platform without issue. So I guess I'm not totally sure what the issue is but if you ever have an issue communicating cross-platform I'd recommend taking a look at the man7 link.

Thanks to everyone for the help!